# Symfony2 After form submit got string instead entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have some error:

> Expected value of type "AdBundle\Entity\AdLocation" for association
>   field "AdBundle\Entity\AdBase#$location", got "string" instead.

Does I need to use DataTransformer? Why I cant use only EntityType field without other manipulations?

AdBase entity:

```
<?php

namespace AdBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * AdBase
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ad_base")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdBundle\Repository\AdBaseRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
    "flat" = "AdFlat"
 *     })
 */
abstract class AdBase
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdBundle\Entity\AdCategory")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdBundle\Entity\AdLocation")
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Not specified Title")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Not specified Description")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AdBundle\Entity\AdPhoto", mappedBy="ad")
     */
    private $photos;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdBundle\Entity\AdPriceType")
     */
    private $priceType;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="createdAt", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updatedAt", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="visible", type="boolean")
     */
    private $visible = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $active = true;


    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param string $author
     *
     * @return AdBase
     */
    public function setAuthor($author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $category
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $location
     */
    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return AdBase
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return AdBase
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set photos
     *
     * @param string $photos
     *
     * @return AdBase
     */
    public function setPhotos($photos)
    {
        $this->photos = $photos;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get photos
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhotos()
    {
        return $this->photos;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $price
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPriceType()
    {
        return $this->priceType;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $priceType
     */
    public function setPriceType($priceType)
    {
        $this->priceType = $priceType;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return AdBase
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param string $updatedAt
     *
     * @return AdBase
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set visible
     *
     * @param boolean $visible
     *
     * @return AdBase
     */
    public function setVisible($visible)
    {
        $this->visible = $visible;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get visible
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getVisible()
    {
        return $this->visible;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $active
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->active = $active;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->author = 'voodoo';
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $this->location = 'Donetsk';
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpdate()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    }
}
```

AdFlat entity:

```
<?php

namespace AdBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * AdFlat
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ad_flat")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdBundle\Repository\AdFlatRepository")
 */
class AdFlat extends AdBase
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="ad_flat.rooms.not_blank")
     */
    private $rooms;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="square", type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $square;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="liveSquare", type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $liveSquare;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $kitchenSquare;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="floor", type="integer")
     */
    private $floor;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="floors", type="integer")
     */
    private $floors;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdBundle\Entity\AdWallType")
     */
    private $wallType;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdBundle\Entity\AdWCType")
     */
    private $wcType;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getRooms()
    {
        return $this->rooms;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $rooms
     */
    public function setRooms($rooms)
    {
        $this->rooms = $rooms;
    }

    /**
     * Set square
     *
     * @param float $square
     *
     * @return AdFlat
     */
    public function setSquare($square)
    {
        $this->square = $square;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get square
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getSquare()
    {
        return $this->square;
    }

    /**
     * Set liveSquare
     *
     * @param float $liveSquare
     *
     * @return AdFlat
     */
    public function setLiveSquare($liveSquare)
    {
        $this->liveSquare = $liveSquare;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get liveSquare
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getLiveSquare()
    {
        return $this->liveSquare;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getKitchenSquare()
    {
        return $this->kitchenSquare;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $kitchenSquare
     */
    public function setKitchenSquare($kitchenSquare)
    {
        $this->kitchenSquare = $kitchenSquare;
    }

    /**
     * Set floor
     *
     * @param integer $floor
     *
     * @return AdFlat
     */
    public function setFloor($floor)
    {
        $this->floor = $floor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get floor
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getFloor()
    {
        return $this->floor;
    }

    /**
     * Set floors
     *
     * @param integer $floors
     *
     * @return AdFlat
     */
    public function setFloors($floors)
    {
        $this->floors = $floors;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get floors
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getFloors()
    {
        return $this->floors;
    }

    /**
     * Set wallType
     *
     * @param string $wallType
     *
     * @return AdFlat
     */
    public function setWallType($wallType)
    {
        $this->wallType = $wallType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wallType
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWallType()
    {
        return $this->wallType;
    }

    /**
     * Set wcType
     *
     * @param string $wcType
     *
     * @return AdFlat
     */
    public function setWcType($wcType)
    {
        $this->wcType = $wcType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wcType
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWcType()
    {
        return $this->wcType;
    }
}
```

AdLocation entity:

```
<?php

namespace AdBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AdLocation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ad_location")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdBundle\Repository\AdLocationRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class AdLocation
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AdBundle\Entity\AdLocation", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdBundle\Entity\AdLocation", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent = null;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $level = 0;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $locationType;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $weight = 0;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="visible", type="boolean")
     */
    private $visible = true;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set children
     *
     * @param string $children
     *
     * @return AdLocation
     */
    public function setChildren($children)
    {
        $this->children = $children;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param string $parent
     *
     * @return AdLocation
     */
    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLevel()
    {
        return $this->level;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $level
     */
    public function setLevel($level)
    {
        $this->level = $level;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return AdLocation
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLocationType()
    {
        return $this->locationType;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $locationType
     */
    public function setLocationType($locationType)
    {
        $this->locationType = $locationType;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getWeight()
    {
        return $this->weight;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $weight
     */
    public function setWeight($weight)
    {
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }

    /**
     * Set visible
     *
     * @param boolean $visible
     *
     * @return AdLocation
     */
    public function setVisible($visible)
    {
        $this->visible = $visible;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get visible
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getVisible()
    {
        return $this->visible;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getParent()) {
            $this->setLevel($this->getParent()->getLevel() + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $categoryId = $request->get('category_id');

        if (!$categoryId) {
            return $this->renderError('Unknown Ad Category');
        }

        $category = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdBundle:AdCategory')->find($categoryId);

        if (null === $category) {
            return $this->renderError('You cannot create Ad for this category');
        }

        if (null === $category->getEntity()) {
            return $this->renderError('You cannot create Ad for category ' . $category->getTitle());
        }

        $adEntity = $this->getEntity($category->getEntity());
        $adForm = $this->getForm($category->getEntity());

        $form = $this->createForm($adForm, $adEntity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $photosDir = $this->getParameter('dir_ad_photo');

            foreach ($form['photos']->getData() as $photo) {
                $adPhoto = new AdPhoto($photo, $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../' . $photosDir);
                $adPhoto->upload();
                $adPhoto->setAd($adEntity);
                $em->persist($adPhoto);
            }

            $adEntity->setCategory($category);

            $em->persist($adEntity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('ad_bundle_ad_view', array(
                'id' => $adEntity->getId()
            ));
        }

        return $this->render('AdBundle:Ad:add-ad-flat.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'adType' => $category->getTitle()
        ));
    }

private function getEntity($className)
    {
        $entityName = 'AdBundle\Entity\\' . $className;

        return new $entityName();
    }

    private function getForm($className)
    {
        $formName = 'AdBundle\Form\Type\\' . $className . 'Type';

        return new $formName();
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand what you want to say.

Comment: From what I saw has no attribute with the File type in their bodies, by exmplo of the photo attribute for the file type, it generates direct form in the right kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, sorry for my question. In first entity version $location property was string, and on prePersist action I do:

```
/**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->author = 'voodoo';
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $this->location = 'Donetsk';
    }
```